How to dynamically update and persist Spring application properties at runtime?
I'm working on a Spring Boot application where I need to allow the admin to dynamically update certain application properties at runtime via a REST API. These properties include both integer and floating-point numbers, some of which represent limits and timeouts, and others are weights used in calculations.
Here are some of the properties that need to be updated:

flag_color_threshold (Default: 7.5)

vote_weight_user (Default: 1)

vote_weight_guest (Default: 0.75)

vote_timeout_user (Default: 1800 seconds)

vote_timeout_guest (Default: 3600 seconds)


The updated values should take effect immediately and should also persist across application restarts.
I've considered using @ConfigurationProperties and @RefreshScope, but I'm unsure how to properly expose an endpoint for this purpose and handle the persistence of the updated values.

Easy answer: use Spring Boot Config Server.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
